# How to change color of dropdown button text on click using viewchild and elementref?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the text in my dropdown menu button change color once it is clicked using `@Viewchild` and `elementRef`. Here is my method but it is not working

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
        (click)="dropdownBtnChangeColor" #dropdownButton>
        Press Me
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <label class="dropdown-item-text text-dark">Sort By</label>
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onSortByChange(opt.value)">
            <i class="text-center"></i>{{ opt.name }}</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <label class="dropdown-item-text">Order By</label>
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onSortDirChange()">
            <i class="text-center"></i>Ascending </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('dropdownButton', {static: false })
    dropdownButton: ElementRef;

 dropdownBtnChangeColor() {
        this.dropdownButton.nativeElement.setAttribute('style', 'color: green');
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean to set color for the selected option's text?

Comment: No the dropdown menu button to show that it was pressed @SivakumarTadisetti

Comment: Is the provided answer worked for you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this one, no need to use `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`. You can simply do it like below

```
dropdownBtnChangeColor(event) {
  ((event as MouseEvent).target as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
    "style",
    "background-color : green"
  );
}
```

Just pass click event from template like below

```
<button ... (click)="dropdownBtnChangeColor($event)">...</button>
```

### Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-dropdown-9jst4y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

If you still want to use `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`, your code is working fine except small mistake. i.e., you missed `()` in the template while calling `dropdownBtnChangeColor`. If you change it from `dropdownBtnChangeColor` to `dropdownBtnChangeColor()` then everything will works fine.

### Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-dropdown-hgrzu9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I learnt something new! Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me...

Comment: @codingkittz can you provide stackblitz with reproducible issue, so will check it. Did you check the provided stackblitz links?

Comment: It's extremely long and is connected to many different files that's why I didn't put it...Hmmm I will try to shorten it and send it later?